# Can a template class alias itself without specifying its template parameters twice?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to define a new class template which has many parameters. For writing some methods (such as overloaded operators), I'd like to alias the template class type. Right now I'm doing it like this:

```
template <class T, int a, int b, int c, int d, int e, int f>
class ExampleClass {

  using ExampleClassType = ExampleClass<T, a, b, c, d, e, f>;

  // for example,
  ExampleClassType operator+(const ExampleClassType& rhs) {
    // ...
  }

};
```

This approach seems redundant, since I'm writing out the list of template parameters twice. Is there a better way? I naively tried

```
using ExampleClassType = decltype(*this);
```

but this doesn't work, I think since `this` is not known at compile time.

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I tried searching but found nothing about this specifically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually just use `ExampleClass` for this purpose. It's called the [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) and inside the class definition you can use it and it will implicitly be the fully instantiated class.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T, int a>
struct ExampleClass
{
    ExampleClass operator+(const ExampleClass& t_rhs) const { std::cout << a << '\n'; return *this; }
};


int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ExampleClass<int, 7> myClass;
    auto foo = myClass + myClass;
}
```

See [on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/P6h8sP4o6).

This will output `7` because in my `operator+`, `ExampleClass` was actually used as an injected class name and meant `ExampleClass<int, 7>`.